# Convert jupyter Notebook code to proper python function

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I have create some code in Jupyter Notebook that pulls data from an API and then writes it to a Dynamodb.
It works fine in Jupyter but fails when I convert it into a python function using def.
Here is the code:

```
import boto3
import pyowm
import time
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, timezone
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


client = boto3.client('ssm')
parameter = client.get_parameter(Name='OpenWeather_API_Key', WithDecryption=False)
ssmkey = parameter['Parameter']['Value']
api_key = print("\"%s\""% ssmkey )
owm = pyowm.OWM(api_key)
city = 'Berlin, DE'

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='aerieous@myserver.com')
location = geolocator.geocode(city)
lat = location.latitude
lon = location.longitude

x = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
d = x.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')

# convert time to epoch
p = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
dt = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d, p)))

url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=%s&lon=%s&dt=%s&appid=%s&units=metric" % (
lat, lon, dt, api_key)
response = requests.get(url)
data_history = json.loads(response.text)

df_history2 = pd.json_normalize(data_history, record_path='hourly', meta=['lat', 'lon', 'timezone'],
                            errors='ignore')
df_history2['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_history2['dt'], unit='s').dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
# replace the column header
df_history2 = df_history2.rename(columns={'dt': 'timestamp'})
df_history2['uuid'] = df_history2[['timestamp', 'timezone']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
df_select_hist2 = df_history2[
['uuid', 'lat', 'lon', 'timezone', 'timestamp', 'temp', 'feels_like', 'humidity', 'pressure']]

# change column types to strings to be on safer side :)
df_select_hist2 = df_select_hist2.astype(str)

# Convert dataframe to list of dictionaries (JSON) that can be consumed by any no-sql database
content = df_select_hist2.to_dict('records')

# create a DynamoDB client
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table("Dev_Weather")

for item in content:
   unique_id = item['uuid']
   location = item['timezone']
   timestamp = item['timestamp']
   lat = item['lat']
   lon = item['lon']
   temp = item['temp']
   feels_like = item['feels_like']
   humidity = item['humidity']
   pressure = item['pressure']

   table.put_item(
      Item={
        'pk_id': unique_id,
        'sk': timestamp,
        'gsi_1_pk': lat,
        'gsi_1_sk': lon,
        'gsi_2_pk': temp,
        'gsi_2_sk': feels_like,
        'humidity': humidity,
        'pressure': pressure,
        'timezone': location
    }
    )
```

I know there must be a function call and some print() involved but I dont know where to put them. merci

A

Comment: What is the error? why does it fail?

Comment: It simply doesn’t write any values to dynamodb where’s when I execute it from Jupyter notebook - it does…

Comment: where is your `def()` code?